# System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a class library project that contains a Resource file. Basically following the pattern of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity. The problem is that at the time of using a resource the exception System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException is raised.

I don't understand why my WebApp crashes when using my library resources and not when using Identity resources.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the Class Library namespace didn't match the Assembly Name. I just set my default namespace for the Assembly name and it works.

I don't like it but whatever...